# Reference for Galileo's Law of Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, history, free-fall

It is stated in some places that one of Galileo's laws of motion is that two objects in free fall in a local gravitational field with different densities will hit the ground at the same time in a vacuum.

Is this actually a ''law of motion'' as Galileo stated it or similar to something he stated, or just a corollary of the other laws?  Is there some reference where he actually writes down laws of motion in the same way that Newton did in the Principia?  Sorry if this is well-known, I don't really know the exact historical details before Newton.

Comment: It really is a consequence of Newton's Universal gravity: $F=G\frac{mM}{R^2}$, where $\frac{GM}{R^2}=g$. So objects, regardless of **mass** $m$, undergo the same acceleration $g$.

Comment: Is there something which I can call it which links it back to the work of Galileo, like Galileo's law, or is there no such thing?

Comment: Not sure. Galileo and Newton weren't contemporaries, so I'm not sure where Galileo got his inspiration from. Perhaps just experiments?

Comment: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei#Falling_bodies

Comment: Galileo's kinematics and some of his astronomical work is contained in his *Dialogue concerning the Two Chief Systems of the World*. The overarching theme of the book is the Copernican vs. the Aristotelian system, but the Galileo's physical reasoning is very clearly given. The book is still in print.

Comment: @PhilipWood It's in Two New Sciences and On Motion. It seems to me that he doesn't have laws and deductions like Newton. It seems that his idea is to analyze motion with experiment and mathematics. Newton was the one who wanted physics to be axiomatic like Euclid.